# Finding the joint moment generating function

Tags: probability

Let X be the value of the first die and Y the sum of
the values when two dice are rolled. Compute the
joint moment generating function of X and Y.

So,

$M_{X,Y}(s,t)=E[e^{sX + tY}] = \sum_{x,y} e^{sx + ty} P(X=x,  Y=y)$

Where $1<=x<=6$ and $2<=Y<=12$

Is that it? It seems lengthy listing all the outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are expected to go further. Let $W$ be the number on the second die. Then $Y=X+W$, and therefore 
$$E(e^{sX+tY})=E(e^{sX+tX+tW})=E(e^{(s+t)X})E(e^{tW}).$$
Each of the expectations on the right-hand side above is relatively easy to write down, as a sum of $6$ items that give a finite geometric progression with a nice sum.